# How can I set different LANGUAGE_CODE for admin site?

Tags: python, django

How can I say this in my settings.py:

```
if *IN ADMIN*
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
else
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-ca'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this link you could find a solution - A Middleware class:
http://source.mihelac.org/2009/11/12/django-set-language-for-admin/